# Memory utilization much higher than it should be

Tags: python, pandas, memory, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm using a simple method to extract descriptors from images and save them to disk into a `.csv` file. I have around 1M images and my network returns 512 features per image (`float32`).

Therefore, I estimate that at the end of the loop I would have `1e6 * 512 * 32/4 / 1e9 = 4.1GB`. However, I observed that it is using more than twice the memory.

`index` is a `string` and `class_id` is a `int64`, so I don't think they are the culprit here.

I have already tried using `gc.collect()` without any success. Do you think my code is leaving references behind?

Here is the method:

```
def prepare_gallery(self, data_loader, TTA, pbar=False, dump_path=None):
    '''Compute embeddings for a data_loader and store it in model.
    This is required before predicting to a test set.
    New entries should be removed from data before calling this function
    to avoid inferring on useless images.
    data_loader: A linear loader containing the database that test is
    compared against.'''
    self.set_mode('valid')
    self.net.cuda()
    n_iter = len(data_loader.dataset) / data_loader.batch_size
    if pbar:
        loader = tqdm(enumerate(data_loader), total=n_iter)
    else:
        loader = enumerate(data_loader)
    # Run inference and get embeddings
    feat_list = []
    index_list = []
    class_list = []
    for i, (index, im, class_id) in loader:
        with torch.no_grad():
            feat = tta(self.net, im)
            # Returns something like np.random.random((32, 512))

        feat_list.extend(feat)
        index_list.extend(index)
        class_list.extend(class_id.item())

    if dump_path is not None:
        np.save(dump_path + '_ids', index_list)
        np.save(dump_path + '_cls', class_list)
        np.save(dump_path + '_feat', feat_list)

    return np.asarray(index_list), np.asarray(feat_list), np.asarray(class_list)
```

Comment: maybe simplify the code a bit to make it reproducible and remove extraneous details?  that said, a `float` in Python (3.7.3) is 24 bytes, have a look at `sys.getsizeof`.  once you put them into `numpy` arrays they can be compacted down to the expected 4 or 8 bytes

Comment: I'll do that! So in my `feat_list` I have a list of 1M elements, where each is a 512d `ndarray`. That means I'll have `1e6 * 512 * 4` bytes, right?

Comment: maybe...  if you could alter the question to show the code you're using to create these arrays it would help me/us see what's going on

Comment: I'll try but it is quite complicated since it is a neural network and it depends on a lot of stuff including data

Comment: just some code to illustrate what numpy arrays are being created, in what format.  e.g. are you ending up with something like `feat_list = [np.zeros(512, np.float32) for _ in range(10**6)]`?